# Replicate a JS and CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to replicate the text animation on the following website.

https://remote.com/

I have found a solution for the animation. However, I can't figure out a way to animate the words one by one. Appreciate it if someone could help with this.

Expected animation

1. Test 1 Animate in - Animate out
2. Test 2 Animate in - Animate out
3. Test 3 Animate in - Animate out

Following is the [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3vyjtq8/3/)

```
var tricksWord = document.getElementsByClassName("tricks");
for (var i = 0; i < tricksWord.length; i++) {

var wordWrap = tricksWord.item(i);
wordWrap.innerHTML = wordWrap.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="tricksword">$2</span>');

}


var tricksLetter = document.getElementsByClassName("tricksword");
for (var i = 0; i < tricksLetter.length; i++) {

   var letterWrap = tricksLetter.item(i);
   letterWrap.innerHTML = letterWrap.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

}


var slideIn = anime.timeline({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
});

slideIn
  .add({
    targets: '.slide-in .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeInOutQuad",
    duration: 2250,
    delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1)
 }).add({
    targets: '.slide-in',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
  

// Slide Up Animation
var slideUp = anime.timeline({
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
});

slideUp
    .add({
    targets: '.slide-up .letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    duration: 750,
    delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
  }).add({
    targets: '.slide-up',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
  
  
// Fade Up Animation
var fadeUp = anime.timeline({
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
});

fadeUp 
  .add({
    targets: '.fade-up .letter',
    translateY: [100,0],
    translateZ: 0,
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 1400,
    delay: (el, i) => 300 + 30 * i
  }).add({
    targets: '.fade-up .letter',
    translateY: [0,-100],
    opacity: [1,0],
    easing: "easeInExpo",
    duration: 1200,
    delay: (el, i) => 100 + 30 * i
  });
  
  
  
// Rotate In Animation
var rotateIn = anime.timeline({
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
});

rotateIn 
    .add({
    targets: '.rotate-in .letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    translateX: ["0.55em", 0],
    translateZ: 0,
    rotateZ: [180, 0],
    duration: 750,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
  }).add({
    targets: '.rotate-in',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
  

// Pop In Animation
var popIn = anime.timeline({
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
});

popIn
    .add({
    targets: '.pop-in .letter',
    scale: [0, 1],
    duration: 1500,
    elasticity: 600,
    delay: (el, i) => 45 * (i+1)
  }).add({
    targets: '.pop-in',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
  

// Play your animation with these
fadeUp.play();
slideUp.play();
slideIn.play();
rotateIn.play();
popIn.play();



// Wait before playing animation
setTimeout(() => {  
    // Put the play below this line
}, 800);
```

Comment: You use some *Text After* which they don't have - since it implies not only words/characters animations but also dynamically shrinking and expanding the width of the element containing the animated words. What about it?

Comment: Currently, the words not animating one after the other. That's the problem. All of the words are animate at once.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ego0pdum/

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I want something like this. https://remote.com/

Comment: Well, I don't know how to use animejs. But see the jsfiddle and all it takes it to make the elements visible on `before`, and hidden on `completed` events. You have a good hint in the example fiddle.